# Qlikview Loop using distinct dates from data

Tags: loops, qlikview, qliksense

i have data for sales of each product by date. I want to show the aggregated sale by product for each day. Please let me know if this is possible.

Sample data:

| Date | Product | Sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | a | 5 |
| 01/01/2020 | b | 12 |
| 01/01/2020 | z | 9 |
| 01/01/2020 | k | 18 |
| 06/01/2020 | a | 18 |
| 07/01/2020 | b | 40 |
| 07/01/2020 | l | 5 |
| 07/01/2020 | k | 9 |
| 11/01/2020 | m | 5 |

I expect the results to show as :

| Date | Product | Sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | a | 5 |
| 01/01/2020 | b | 12 |
| 01/01/2020 | z | 9 |
| 01/01/2020 | k | 18 |
| 06/01/2020 | a | 23 |
| 06/01/2020 | b | 12 |
| 06/01/2020 | z | 9 |
| 06/01/2020 | k | 18 |
| 07/01/2020 | a | 23 |
| 07/01/2020 | b | 52 |
| 07/01/2020 | z | 9 |
| 07/01/2020 | k | 27 |
| 07/01/2020 | l | 5 |
| 11/01/2020 | a | 23 |
| 11/01/2020 | b | 52 |
| 11/01/2020 | z | 9 |
| 11/01/2020 | k | 27 |
| 11/01/2020 | l | 5 |
| 11/01/2020 | m | 5 |

Answer (score 0):

Check out the annotated script but the general steps are:

- create temp table that contins the `min` date for each product (aka date of the first sale)

  [image]
- another table that contains all possible combinations between dates and products

  [image]
- join both temp tables back to the raw data table

  [image]
- exclude rows for which the sale date is less than or equal to the min sale date (`Where Date >= MinDate`).

  [image]
- at this point we have the data ready and can make the calculation that will give us the aggregated sale

  [image]

Annotated script:

```
RawData:
Load * inline [
Date,       Product, Sold
01/01/2020, a,       5
01/01/2020, b,       12
01/01/2020, z,       9
01/01/2020, k,       18
06/01/2020, a,       18
07/01/2020, b,       40
07/01/2020, l,       5
07/01/2020, k,       9
11/01/2020, m,       5
];

// find the first sale date for each product
MinDates:
Load 
  Date(min(Date), 'DD/MM/YYYY') as MinDate,
  Product
Resident
  RawData
Group By 
  Product
;

// create table with all possible dates and products
TempTable1:
Load Distinct
  Date
Resident 
  RawData
;

join

Load Distinct
  Product
Resident 
  RawData
;

// join both temp tables to the main data table
// and drop the temp tables
join (RawData)

Load * Resident TempTable1;

Drop Table TempTable1;

join (RawData)

Load * Resident MinDates;

Drop Table MinDates;

// filter out records for which the sale date is 
// less than or equal of the first sale date
NoConcatenate

RawData1:
Load 
  * 
Resident 
  RawData
Where
  Date >= MinDate 
;

Drop Table RawData;

// once we have the data in the right format we can calculate aggregated sale amount
// for each record:
//   * if the current Product value is not equal to the previous one - get the Sold amount
//   * else if Sold amount is not null - get the current Sold amound and add the previous AggregatedSale amount
//   * else get the previous AggregatedSale amount
NoConcatenate

FinalTalbe:
Load 
  Date,
  Product,
  Sold,
  if(Product <> peek(Product), Sold,
    if(Sold <> null(), Sold + peek(AggregatedSale), peek(AggregatedSale))
  ) as AggregatedSale
Resident
  RawData1
Order By
  Product,
  Date  
;

Drop Table RawData1;
```